# proper way to show a list of options in iOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I've have a `UIViewController` that contains a number of views, one of which is a button (whose label shows a default option) that, when pressed, opens up a new `UIViewController` that contains a `UICollectionView` consisting of a number of options. When one of the items in the `UICollectionView` is selected, we return to the original `UIViewController` and the item in the `UICollectionView` becomes the label of the button that was pressed in the original `UIViewController`.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to set this up. I'm more familiar with the Android platform and the desired functionality was easier to set up. all I needed to do was to create a full screen dialog and when an item is pressed dismiss the dialog and change the button title. However, in iOS, the `AlertController` class seems to be limited in functionality (I tried adding a `UICollectionView` as a subview, but it didn't work out too well). So, I continued reading about the difference between the Android and iOS design guidelines and based off what I read I should be using a modal `UIViewController`. However, I want to be able to go back to the original `UIViewController` if an option isn't selected so I set a `UINavigationController` with both VCs in the stack. When I select the modal segue option in storyboard, the 2nd VC doesn't show the back button, but when I choose the normal show option, the back button shows. When a item is pressed, a reference to the first VC is created, the button label is changed and the 2nd VC gets popped off the stack (ideally).

I would like to know the proper (best) way to set up the desired functionality in the iOS environment. Also, I'd like to know by what metric the your grading the method on?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need AlertController. I know if I were doing this, I would not need it.

Comment: i think of alertcontroller like a dialog in android. the android solution uses a dialog show my first thought was to use alertcontroller in the ios solution

Comment: AlertController isn't designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is how to make ViewControllers talk to each other. 
There are a few ways to do this.

1. In one view controller, keep a variable pointing to the other view controller.
   In your case, create a variable in the destination that points back to the caller.
   When you dismiss the destination, after making your selection, 
   use the variable to update the caller.
2. Use Notifications. This is an indirect way for any object to call another object. 
   You have to set these up in advance, but it is very useful especially when the 
   classes in question don't naturally interact.

Here is how to do 1.

Add a segue from your calling view controller to the destination view controller. 
In StoryBoard, give the seque a name so you can recognize it later.

On the calling view controller, make sure you have an outlet for the button.
Add the outlet using the StoryBoard editor.

When the button is pressed, have it trigger the segue.

In your calling view controller, make sure there is a `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`.
In this function, add code to detect which segue was triggered by using the name you set on the storyboard.
If you only have one segue, you can leave this out.

In the function add this:

```
    if segue.identifier == "your-segue-identifier-string" {
        if let dest = segue.destination as? OptionsViewController {
            dest.bookmarkViewController = self
        }
    }
```

In the OptionsViewController, add a var to bookmark the calling view controller.
Make it optional(using ?).

```
var bookmarkViewController: MyParentViewController?
```

In MyParentViewController, add a function that updates the button title.

```
func updateButton(title: String) {
    // Update button title here using the outlet.
}
```

In OptionsViewController, when an option is selected, use the bookmarkViewController var to call the button update function in the caller.

```
self.bookmarkViewController.updateButton(title: new-title-goes-here)
// dismiss the options view controller.
```